# Compilation Error in perl script while giving present date in input file name

Tags: perl

As per below script, Trying to give two Input files. Test_DDD111_20120731.csv and DDD111.txt.
Inside one folder this Test_DDD111*.csv file with different date will be available. I want to give only current date file as input inside this script.

I assign date as $deviationreportdate. But i am getting error, can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Error which i am getting:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at subscriberdump.pl line 58, near "/Test_DDD(\d+)/${deviationreportdate}"
        (Missing operator before ${deviationreportdate}?)
        syntax error at subscriberdump.pl line 58, near "/Test_DDD(\d+)/${deviationreportdate}"
        Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use strict;
use POSIX;

my @array123;

my $daysbefore;
my %month="";

my ($f2_field, @patterns, %patts, $f2_rec);


while (@ARGV)

{
  my $par=shift;

  if( $par eq "-d" )

  {

    $daysbefore=shift;

    next;
  }
}

sub getDate
{
        my $daysago=shift;

        $daysago=0 unless ($daysago);

        my @months=qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);

        my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = 

Localtime(time(86400*$daysago));

        # YYYYMMDD, e.g. 20060126

        return sprintf("%d%02d%02d",$year+1900,$mon+1,$mday);
}

my $deviationreportdate=getDate($daysbefore-1);

my $transactiondate=getDate($daysbefore);

my $filename="output.txt");

open(OUTPUTFILE,"> /tmp/$filename");

for my $Test_file (<Test_DDD*${deviationreportdate}*>) 

{

  if ($Test_file =~ /Test_DDD(\d+)/${deviationreportdate}*) 

{

    my $file = "DDD$1.txt";

    my $ID="DDD$1"; 

    open AIN, "<$file"    or die($file);

    open BIN, "<$Test_file" or die($Test_file);

    my %seen;
}
```

Comment: please fix your code. And what are you trying to do with the regex?

Comment: well, the two lines giving syntax errors are...syntax errors.  and it's really hard to guess what you intend them to do.  maybe you could describe exactly what you expect the for and if to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, As i mentioned before, inside one folder i have so many files like Test_DDD111_20120731.csv and another file DDD111.txt. I just want to give those two files as input. I am doing some comparision. That comparision script is working fine. But i want that script automatically fetch current date file and do the same process. If DDD111 in both csv and txt file are same, then i want to give those file has input and date should be present date.

Comment: Example file names: Test_DDD111_20120731.csv,DDD111.txt,Test_DDD222.20120731.csv,DDD222.txt.... so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression is invalid

`$Test_file =~ /Test_DDD(\d+)/${deviationreportdate}*`

you can only have modifiers after the last slash in a regex. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with this, otherwise I would post the correct regex for you. maybe you ment this?

`$Test_file =~ /Test_DDD(\d+)\/${deviationreportdate}*/`

or this

`$Test_file =~ /Test_DDD(\d+)${deviationreportdate}*/`

Comment: hi John, this what i want, now its working fine. One small error is coming can u suggest why it is coming.                              # perl test.pl -d 1
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at test.pl line 10.
DeviationReportdate::20120731
TransactionDate::20120730

Comment: @Mike That would be due to this: `my %month="";` which is trying to initialize a hash with an empty string.  Doesn't make any sense.  `%month` isn't used in the code anyway.